Does Anyone Have a Profile For Contour ShuttlePro v2
I have a Contour ShuttlePro that I love using with Photoshop and Davinci resolve. It does not have a built in profile for Blender and so I wondered if anyone has created on they would like to share.
Thanks
Rich
